# How do I create a FetchRequest predicate for a child entity where the parent entity satisfies a NSPredicate

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have two Core Data entities: `Parent` and `Child`.
`Parent` has a property `children` for the set of children

Each `Child` has a `parent` property linking it to its parent, and an `age` property.
(My data is more complex than this, but that's not relevant to the question)

I have a `NSPredicate` for the `Parent` entity that selects a set of parents and a `NSPredicate` for the `Child` entity that selects entities based on age

What I want to do is construct a single `NSPredicate` for a `FetchRequest<Child>` that returns the set of `Child` entities that meets both of the individual predicates

I know I can retrieve an array of `Parent` entities that meet their predicate ('`parents`') then have a child predicate something like `NSPredicate(format: "parent IN %@", parents)` and include that in a compound AND with the child predicate, but there could be hundreds of parents meeting their predicate and it looks to me a but of a kludge to have two separate queries.

The `FetchRequest` needs to be `FetchRequest<Child>` as it's used in a SwiftUI view, so I can't just build an array of the results.

I suspect that I can do this with a SUBQUERY predicate but I can't work out how to embed the parent predicate into the SUBQUERY. I get errors like `Problem with subpredicate TRUEPREDICATE` in the predicate string for the `Parent` entity.

Hopefully that makes sense? Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What is the predicate for the parent entity?

Comment: It's a predicate generated by a set of user-input criteria so it varies. In the query I'm asking about I access it through a function that returns a NSPredicate.

Comment: Each child has only one parent?

Comment: Yes, it's one -> many (Parent -> Child)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the relationship from `Child` to `Parent` is to-one, then there is no need for SUBQUERY.  In the format string for the parent predicate (which you can obtain with `predicateFormat`), you can replace each parent attribute name in the the string with the keypath to that attribute from the child, ie

> `attribute` becomes `parent.attribute`

The resulting predicate can then be combined with the child predicate using `NSCompoundPredicate`'s `andPredicateWithSubpredicates`.

If parsing the predicateFormat is impractical, another option is to use `NSFetchRequestExpression` to pass the results of one fetch as an argument to another (it gets converted to an SQL subselect).  Something like this:

```
let parentFetch = Parent.fetchRequest()
parentFetch.predicate = parentPredicate // your existing predicate to fetch the parent objects
parentFetch.resultType = .managedObjectIDResultType
let ctxtExp = NSExpression(forConstantValue: managedObjectContext)
let fetchExp = NSExpression(forConstantValue: parentFetch)
let fre = NSFetchRequestExpression.expression(forFetch: fetchExp, context: ctxtExp, countOnly: false) 
let childFetch = Child.fetchRequest()
let subPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"parent IN %@",fre)
let combinedPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [subPredicate, childPredicate]) // childPredicate is you existing predicate to fetch the correct Child objects
childFetch.predicate = combinedPredicate
... proceed to execute the fetch against the relevant context
```

Comment: However the parent predicate can involve up to around 10 attributes with different matching criteria set by the app user at run time so a formula to reliably search and replace each attribute name in a predicate string is non-trivial and potentially error prone at run time. I would prefer to use the parent predicate unchanged if there is a way to do it as this has been fully tested

Comment: Thanks , I think that looks promising particularly if it’s converted to a SQL subquery. I’ll give it a go tomorrow (I’m in the UK so it’s late now!)

Comment: I'm not sure that's going to work - the subquery is throwing an exception complaining that it can't generate the SQL: 
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (parent IN FETCH(<NSFetchRequest: 0x60000127a610> (entity: Parent; predicate: (startDate >= CAST(599529600.000000, "NSDate") AND (activityType == "Ride")); sortDescriptors: ((
)); type: NSManagedObjectIDResultType; includesPropertyValues: NO; ), <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600000214b60>, NO))'`

Comment: Strange.  Can you show your entity definitions and the parent predicate?

Comment: My mistake: looking at it again, when I copied over your suggested code I didn't change the string "parent IN ..." to the actual parent entity property name on the child entity (it's not 'parent'...). Just fixed that and it works perfectly! Thanks for the suggestion and I've learned something new...