# Check object with CoreData predicate

Tags: swift, core-data

I use Core Data to find CatalogItem with predicate "parentId == 3". And I want to check in this predicate also if is exist item with CatalogItem.parentId == id". This "id" is from result item of first query part. Is it possible to use id, which i don't know yet?

[image]

Comment: How is this related to the <sql> language?

Comment: @jarlh, because sql is under CoreData. Maybe somebody know how to make subquery on sql to solve this question.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64090906/how-do-i-create-a-fetchrequest-predicate-for-a-child-entity-where-the-parent-ent) could be of some help.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, no( The main question is: can i use "id" from first predicate and put it in the second predicate, and that's all in 1 predicate.

Comment: Ok but when I read your question again I wonder why you don't have a relation from CatalogItem (parent) to CatalogItem (children)?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, yes, it's a good question! I asked it to my self) This probably can be solution, but maybe anybody know how to use field from fetch with second part predicate 
at once.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson, because it wasn't need before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hesitate to provide this answer, because (as @JoakimDanielson says in comments) a better solution is to implement a reflexive relationship from `CatalogItem` to itself.  However, if that's not an option, I think the following variation on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64092529/3985749) to a similar question should achieve what you need:

```
let parentFetch = CatalogItem.fetchRequest()
parentFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"parentId == 3")
parentFetch.propertiesToFetch = ["id"]
let ctxtExp = NSExpression(forConstantValue: managedObjectContext)
let fetchExp = NSExpression(forConstantValue: parentFetch)
let fre = NSFetchRequestExpression.expression(forFetch: fetchExp, context: ctxtExp, countOnly: false) 
let childFetch = CatalogItem.fetchRequest()
childFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"parentId IN %@",fre)
... proceed to execute the fetch against the relevant context
```

Comment: I solved my problem by making new relation between items. But your answer looks like what i wanted.